Why does post-synthesis propagation delay vary for the exact same LUT6 primitive, with the same I2_O path and same fan-out?

Please consider the last two Prop_LUT6_I2_O logic delays above at 90ps and 32ps respectively.
Why does the timing-model for the same I2_O LUT path have such high variance, and ideas? Even the net-delay is constant between the two at 187 ps.
They both have fan-out=1, and both drive a single I3 pin of the next LUT. I'd expect similar I2_O paths of identical LUT primitives with equivalent fan-outs to have the same logic delay.
And lastly, a general question, does Vivado only account for fan-out in the net-delay, or does it account for it in both the logic and net delay? I can see the case for doing it in both places:
a) Increased fan-out of course means greater RC delay across the nets
b) Increased fan-out/load-capacitance on a primitive output pin means a greater (rise/fall) transition time to either charge or discharge the required (increased) capacitance.
Curious as to how/where does Vivado account for these two physical consequences of higher fan-out?
